# Visual Studio 2010 setup project: How to set company name used in default install location?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation

I have a console app project and a related setup project in the same solution. When I run the generated .msi, the install wizard shows following default Install location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\myApp\
```

How can I put my own company name?

Comment: Simplest way is to open the actual file that is used to create the msi, and do a find for 'Default Company Name' and change it. There is a way to do it in the editor, but I don't have vs2010 installed at the moment, and that is gone in 2012. Just right click on your setup project and open in windows explorer.

Comment: got it. i had to change the "deployment project properties" of my setup project. For company name change value of 'Manufacturer'.this can be accessed by selecting the setup project while properties window is open.

Comment: Change the Author property in Setup project properties

Answer (score 59):

Open the Properties Window (NOT the right-click on the set-up project)

Use the toolbar **View -> Properties Window**

**VS 2013/2017 on windows 7**:
Keyboard shortcut <kbd>F4</kbd>

**VS 2010 on windows 7**: 
Keyboard shortcut sequence <kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd>

Now select your set-up project in the Solution Explorer window, the Properties window should populate with the info (e.g. author, language, program title etc.) that you can edit

Answer (score 16):

Select the project in solution explorer and hit <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

For changing the following default Install location

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\myAppSetup\

- Select the set-up project "myAppSetup" in solution explorer and hit **F4**.
- Change the **Manufacturer** property "Default Company Name" in properties window to your own company name, e.g. "StackOverflow".
- Change the **ProductName** property "myAppSetup" in properties window to your desired program name, e.g. "Sweepstakes".
- The **Author** property may contain a default value "Default Company Name" and can also be changed.

Then the Install location will be like this

> C:\Program Files (x86)\StackOverflow\Sweepstakes\

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the Default Company Name visible in control panel in **Publisher** column, then change the Manufacturer property in properties window of setup project.

if you want to change the program name as visible in **Name** column in control panel please change the **ProductName** in properties window.