# In Visual Basic 2019, how do I set the installation directory for published projects?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, installation, directory, visual-studio-2019

I think this issue should have a simple solution.  It should be a common desire of people programming using Visual Studio, but I have not been able to locate a solution to my problem, either in a book or online.

I am able to publish my visual studio project using the Publish Wizard.  However, when I install the published program on my PC, the installation is deep in a maze of directories and inside a file with a bunch of random letters and numbers in its name.  Here is where it installed:

```
C:\Users\Earl\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Z29TCPE5.944\RK99RK5P.J9K\basi..tion_71f32d96f76160a3_0001.0000_a14a9b8e58a3836c
```

I would like the installation to take place in the "C:\Program Files" directory so it is easy for the end user to locate and update the text files included with the program.

Is this possible?  Seems like it should be easy to do.  I am grateful for any help you could provide.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is part of the internal behavior of ClickOnce and [can't (shouldn't) be altered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11208070/722393). Idea: why not add the ability to open these text files as a feature of your program? That'd be even easier for the user. Example: `Process.Start($"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)}\MyApp\File.txt")`.

Comment: The program is for students to study a variety of subjects.  The questions and answers are in the text files read by the program.  Some files will contain several hundred questions, so it's a lot easier to edit the several text files, put a bunch of information in them and start the program.  That being said, perhaps the program could tell the user the location of the text files.  Alternatively, I could just have them search the C drive for the appropriate file names.  Being realistic, I know that the easier it is for the student to find the files, the more likely they are to use the program.

Comment: Also wanted to say thank you for the information.  (I ran out of characters to use in the above comment.)

Comment: It sounds to me like you're inviting user error. Any number of problems could occur between their edits and your reads. Best to use a database, I'd say. That way you have a lot more control over enforcing rules.

Comment: *Also wanted to say thank you* YW

Comment: While I agree with what @InteXX has suggested about using a DB, could always use a setup and deployment project which you can get from the VS market and gives you a bit more control over the installer

Comment: You may need to check following document: [How to: Publish a ClickOnce application using the Publish Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2019)